# why we using closures in g:select optionvalue

Tags: grails, groovy, closures

I can understand what is Closures. i can understand below example.

```
    def list = ['a','b','c','d']
    def newList = []

    def clos = { it.toUpperCase() }
    list.collect( newList, clos )

assert newList == ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
```

I went to see g:select documentation. i saw below.

```
 <g:select optionKey="id" optionValue="${{it.title?.toUpperCase()}}" name="book.title" from="${bookList}" />
```

I did't understand ${{it.title?.toUpperCase()}}.

i understand the logic that for each object title is converted to uppercase, but why we need  double "{}"..

**why it did not work using ${it.title?.toUpperCase()}**

documentation link [enter link description here](http://grails.org/doc/1.0.x/ref/Tags/select.html#)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The outher ${ } is not a closure, is a [GSP Expression](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#expressions), only the inner {} is a closure. If you put only ${it.title?.toUpperCase()} you don't pass the parameter a closure but the actual "it.title?.toUpperCase()" resolved value.